# Android SQLite Escaping Where Clause

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Do where clauses need to be escaped for SQLite in Android?

```
ContentValues vals= new ContentValues();
vals.put(KEY, val);

String where = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(val);

db.update(TABLE_NAME, vals, KEY + "='" + where + "'", null);
```

For some reason if I do `db.update(TABLE_NAME, vals, KEY + "=?", new String[] {where});` it doesn't work.

**EDIT:** My question is whether I need to escape `where` with `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString`  or if the `update` method (or any of the other SQLite methods) will escape it for me.

Comment: ANYTHING you're inserting into an sql string needs to be escaped if it could potentially contain sql metacharacters. e.g. consider `WHERE key='Miles O'Brien'`.

Comment: I guess my question is more if the `update` method escapes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [update() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) expects a SQL WHERE clause in the third parameter slot, not an escaped parameter value.  It expects an array of values to plug into the WHERE clause, not the word "where".

Here is the method signature:

```
public int update (
    String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Comment: `where` is just the variable name. It is set to `DatabseUtils.sqlEscapeString(val)` and contains the SQL-escaped val.

Comment: Then maybe you ought to be more specific about the error message you are getting.

Comment: In terms of using a `String[]` vs putting the whole where clause into `whereClause`, I don't get an actual error when I use a `String[]`; it just doesn't find my rows that for sure meet the criteria for the where clause, while passing the whole clause in with the `whereClause` argument does find the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(stringToEscape)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html

Comment: That's what I'm using now. My question really should be whether the `update` method escapes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

where is assumed in the sqllite update method.

```
ContentValues vals= new ContentValues();
vals.put(KEY, val);
db.update(TABLE_NAME, vals, KEY + " = ?",new String[] {String.valueOf(DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(val)) });
```